# Regex to match all alphanumeric and math operators

Tags: c#, regex

I have the simple regex @"[a-zA-Z]" to match all characters a-z in a string but I also need math operators (*, /, +, -). I was reading over the documentation on msdn but I got lost relatively fast due to the math operators being used as other tokens in the regex

This solution works:

```
 @"[A-Za-z\*\+\-\/]"
```

Thanks for the help and resources everyone.

Comment: depending on the engine, you should be fine with just using `[a-zA-Z*/+-]` as long as theyre inside of the `[]` block.

Comment: If you are satisfied with an answer, then you need to select the accepted answer.  Don't forget to recognize/reward those who have helped you.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that JimN, I am fairly new to this site.

Comment: If you have solution that works what *exactly* you are asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is

```
@"[A-Za-z*+/-]"
```

Or `@"[A-Za-z-*+/]"`, or `@"[-A-Za-z*+/]"`, or `@"[A-Za-z*\-+/]"`.

Or, shorten it with a case-insensitive modifier: `@"(?i)[A-Z*+/-]"` (or use a corresponding `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` with `@"[A-Z*+/-]"` since it seems you are using C#).

Inside a character class, the unescaped hyphen should either be at the start or final position to be treated as a literal, or right after a range or shorthand class. Otherwise, it must be escaped. Also, `]` must be escaped if not at the beginning of the character class. Other characters do not have to be escpaed inside a character class.

To test, use an appropriate online regex tester. You need one for .NET, see [Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5BA-Za-z*%2B%2F-%5D&i=azAZ-%2B%2F-) at [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester).